# EF core - the most effective query in this case

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

Sorry for the illegibility, I have to use code anonymization

I use EF Core and have 4 database entities:

```
class A
{
 public int AId {get; set;}
 public ICollection<AB> ABs {get; set;}
}

class AB
{
 public int ABId {get; set;}
 public A A {get; set;}
 public B B {get; set;}  
}

class B
{
 public int BId {get; set;}
 public ICollection<AB> ABs {get; set;}
 public ICollection<C> Cs {get; set;}
}

class C
{
 public int CId {get; set;}
 public int UId {get; set;}
 public B B {get; set;} 
}
```

I am looking for the most effective query. I get `AId` and `UId`. I would like to get `A` where `AId.AId = AId` with all `C` where `C.UId = UId`. If there is no `C` with `UId` for some `B` (in `A->AB->B->C`) I would like to return  new `C` {`B = B`} for that `B`.

I wrote something like this and later operate on this object. But I think it is not effective, because I load all UQ from database

```
var result = context.QS
            .Where(qs => qs.QSId == QSId)
            .Include(qs => qs.QSQ)
            .ThenInclude(qsq => qsq.Q)
            .ThenInclude(q => q.UQ)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Its surprising how hard this is to understand with qs us uqs qids uids and s's

Comment: I'd even be inclined to believe its on purpose...

Comment: Sorry for the illegibility, I have to use code anonymization on stackoverflow. I can use A, B, C but i don't think that will be better

Comment: It's easier to see and understand if you use A, B, C and D.

Comment: what do you mean by "most effective"?

Comment: the query with the lowest load on the database

Comment: write the sql which does what u want then right it as linq joins https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/linq/sql-joins-with-csharp-linq

Comment: @GertArnold you missed the boat, writing the sql helps you know how to write the linq. otherwise just write the linq if you already know, but when working with OOP a lot of the time what is simple in OOP is not directly translatable to SQL, so the better ur understanding of sql and how it can be writen will help with the writing of the appropriate linq.

Comment: @Seabizkit Knowing OOP/LINQ w/o knowing SQL is one of the main benefits of using ORM. While it might not be able to translate some constructs with no direct SQL equivalent, it translates very well auto joins represented by navigation properties, so Gert is right (and this is common agreement by people working with EF6 / EF Core) that manual joins or `GroupBy` should be used only in very rare cases as last resort when there is no appropriate navigation properties. Which is not the case with OP sample model.

Comment: @IvanStoev i think u also missed me, in this case is straight join's and I provided a link to show how it would be done, I am totally an advocate for using ORM. I was simply saying that i have en-counted a lot of ppl who totally forget that the abstractions of the ORM have to be converted to sql, when doing so, it can not always work out the best sql to do the abstraction so, sometime its better for performance to work out the other ways that the ORM allows you to be more specific in what your wanting. A lot of the time, it helps to write the sql. help you right the required linq.

Answer (score 0):

> When using entity framework always use `Select` to select items, and Select only the properties that you plan to use. Only use `Include` if you plan to update the fetched items.

A database management system is extremely optimized to select values, way better than your local process. The slower part of a database query is the transfer of the selected values from the DBMS to your local process. Hence it is wise to select only the properties that you actually plan to use.

For example. Suppose you have a schools database, with a straightforward one-to-many relation between Schools and Students: every School has zero or more Students, and every Student attends exactly one School, namely the School that foreign key SchoolId refers to.

Now if you query "School [10] with all its 2000 Students", you know that every Student of this School will have a foreign key `SchoolId` with a value of 10. If you would use Include, you would transfer this value 10 2000 times, while you already fetched the value, namely the primary key of School.

Another advantage of using Select is that you can decouple your database tables from the results. If you later will change your database table, for instance add a column, or rename it, then the users of your queries won't have to change as long as they don't need the value of the newly added column.

### virtual ICollection

A side remark: shouldn't the properties that express the relations between your tables not be virtual?

> In entity framework the columns of your tables are represented by non-virtual properties; the virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...).

Hence a foreign key is non-virtual; the object that the foreign key refers to should be declared virtual.

### Back to your question

**Requirement**: Given a QSId and a UId, get all QSses where QSId.QSId = QSId, each QS with all their UQs where UQ.UId = UId, or a default UQ if there are no UQs.

There are two methods for this: user the ICollection, in which case entity framework will know

### Method using the ICollections

This method works with full entity framework. Sometimes I hear that EF core doesn't support this. You know core better than I do, so maybe you should edit this part of the answer.

```
int QSId = ...
int UId = ...
var result = dbContext.QSses
    .Where(qs => qs.Id == QSId)
    .Select(qs => new
    {
         // Select only the QS properties that you plan to use:
         Id = qs.Id,  // not really needed, you already know that it equals QSId
         Name = qs.Name,
         ...

         UQs = qs.QSQs.SelectMany(qsq => qsq.UQs)
             .Where(uq => uq.UId == Uid)
             .Select(uq => new UQ
             {
                  // Only the properties that you plan to use:
                  Id = uq.UqId,
                  Name = uq.Name,
                  ...
             })
             .ToList(),
    })
```

The problem is, that if your qs has no UQs at all, you want a default value. The smartest is to transfer the empty collection to your local process, and if you detect that it is empty, use a new default item.

Continuing the code above:

```
// Transfer to local process:
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(qs => new
{
    Id = qs.Id
    Name = qs.Name,
    ...

    UQs = qs.UQs.Any() ? qs.UQs : new List<UQ>() {new UQ {...}},
});
```

Whenever possible I use the method with the `virtual ICollections`, instead of doing a GroupJoin yourself. IMHO it looks way more similar to your requirements.

### Do the (Group-)Joins yourself

Some people don't trust that entity framework creates the correct (Group-)Joins, or they use a version of entity framework (or provider) that doesn't support using the virtual ICollections. In that case you'll have to do the GroupJoins yourself.

> When going from one to many, use GroupJoin. When going from many-to-one use Join.

So To the junction table: GroupJoin, from the junction table to your UQ use Join.

```
var result = dbContext.QSses
    .Where(qs => qs.Id == QSId)
    .GroupJoin(dbContext.QSQs,
        qs => qs.Id,        // from every QS take the primary key
        qsq => qsq.QSId,    // from every QSQ take the foreign key to the QS

        // parameter resultSelector: from every QS with its zero or more QSQs make one new
        (qs, qsqs) => new
        {
            Id = qs.Id,
            Name = qs.Name,
            ...

         // To get the UQs belonging to these qsqs, do a Join
         // not a GroupJoin, every qsq has exactly one UQ.
         UQs = qs.QSQs.Join(dbContext.UQs.Where(uq => uq.UId == Uid),
             qsq => qsq.UQId,    // take the foreign key to the UQ
             uq => uq.Id,        // take the primary key

             // parameter resultSelector, take the qsq with its matching uq
             (qsq, uq) => new
             {
                  Id = uq.UqId,
                  Name = uq.Name,
                  ...
             })
             .ToList(),
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(... See above);
```

Comment: Please stop repeating this "virtual" misconception. Not sure where you got this, but  relationships are represented by **navigation** properties - see [Relationships - Definitions of Terms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#definition-of-terms) in **official** EF Core documentation. And navigation properties do not need to be virtual. In EF Core virtual is needed ONLY for lazy loading with lazy loading proxies.

Comment: Also in EF Core LINQ queries navigation properties are fully supported, while `GroupJoin`s are not supported at all. In general you can't use your EF6 knowledge/experience with EF Core, you have to learn/play with it in order to take into account its specifics when dealing with such issues. And test suggestions before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? I got only 1 data of TableC.

```
var tableA = db.TableA.Where(x => x.TableAid == 2)
                      .Include(x => x.TableAb)
                      .Include("TableAb.TableB")
                      .Include("TableAb.TableB.TableC")
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, but it can be few C for B or no C for B and I need select C with specific UId or new C